# Detecting objects using blender

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I have to implement a problem statement in blender.

1. **I have different objects scattered on a plane.**(e.g. Object1,Object2,Object3)
2. **I have to model a car which moves using 4 set of keys on the keyboard and it should detect these scattered objects on the
       place.**

**How can I detect these objects using blender?**

Comment: Collision Detection

Comment: Are you talking about Blender or the BGE? You tags are ambiguous.